# Python selenium WebDriverException: chrome not reachable while opening ChromeDriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chrome Webdriver to open a webpage in Python 3.
I would like to have a function that can open the  webpage. 
I originally had:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\alice\Desktop\chromedriver')
driver.get('https://reports.blm.gov/report/LR2000/23/Pub-MC-Geo-Index')
```

I put it in to a function goTo()

```
def goTo():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\alice\Desktop\chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://reports.blm.gov/report/LR2000/23/Pub-MC-Geo-Index')
```

However, I was unable to do any other action on that page outside of that goTo function. When try I get error:

```
WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Does anyone knows how can I open the a page properly using a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.36*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.35*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you so much! You saved my day :)